PostGres how to cast function input on call
I have the following function def:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.myFunction(businessId bigint)
    ...
END
$$

I tried calling it in dbeaver the following way:
SELECT * FROM public.myFunction(4)

But I get:
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I tried calling with:
SELECT * FROM public.myFunction(CAST(4 AS BigInt))

I get the same error, how can I call this function exactly? It does exist in the db function list (it's listed as an int8 parameter)
Please note this does work when being called through the Java JPA application, just not through the sql script in dbeaver.

Most likely an issue with the UPPERcase in your function name. Never ever use UPPER case, you will have bugs forever.
